# Consider the topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by the basis $\{[a, b) : a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$. What is the closure of the set $(0,\sqrt 2)$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Consider the topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by the basis $\left \{[a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb Q\right \}$. Denote the topology by $\Gamma_l$. What is the closure of the set $(0,\sqrt 2)$ in $\Gamma_l$?

The guess candidates are $\left [0,\sqrt 2\right )$, $\left (0,\sqrt 2\right ]$ and $\left [0,\sqrt 2\right ]$. Out of these, I could eliminate $\left [0,\sqrt 2\right )$ since
$$\left [0,\sqrt 2\right )=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left [0,q_n\right )$$
where $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt 2$, and $q_1>0$.

[**Note:** As Theo pointed out, it does not eliminate the possiblity. Being open does not imply that it's not closed]

But, I am unable to perform such manipulations on $\left (0,\sqrt 2\right ]$ or $\left [0,\sqrt 2\right ]$. I tried to look at the complement of $\left (0,\sqrt 2\right ]$ which is $(-\infty,0]\cup\left (\sqrt 2,\infty\right )$ one of which is closed and the other is open.

I would like to know whether there are any tricks to guess the closure of such sets in these weird topologies, and a proof for the current problem.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why does the infinite union exclude the possibility of $[0, \sqrt{2})$? This shows the set is open, but it doesn't necessarily imply that it's not closed.

Comment: @TheoBendit oh yes! That's a good point! I am new to these things, and I keep forgetting that in these weird circumstances, natural looking sets may also be clopen :( But, I mentioned that it's an *increasing* sequence of rationals

Comment: As a hint, I would recommend thinking in terms of proving a point $x \in \Bbb{R}$ is **not** in the closure by finding a (basic) neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus [0, \sqrt{2})$. Can you see why any point $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [0, \sqrt{2}]$ is not in the closure? Can you do the same for $0$ and/or $\sqrt{2}$? If you can't, they belong in the closure!

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for the hint. Please check my argument here- the answer is not $[/(0,\sqrt 2]$ since we cannot find basic open set containing $\sqrt 2$ and contained in $[/(0,\sqrt 2]$. So the answer (ironically) is $[0,\sqrt 2)$. But, can you show or give a hint for a proof?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what $[/(0, \sqrt{2}]$ and $(\sqrt{2}, 0]$ mean?

Comment: @TheoBendit I just wrote $[0,\sqrt 2]$ and $(0,\sqrt 2]$ together (sorry for the abuse of notation). The other one is edited

Comment: @TheoBendit I think I also completed the proof.

Comment: Wonderful! If you want me (and possibly others) to check it, I suggest posting an answer to your question. Put up the top of your answer that you're looking for feedback. It's good to get these questions answered, and, as per usual, the person I prefer to answer questions is the person who asked it. ;-)

Comment: @TheoBendit is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4377628/943723) fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint for the procedure: if $A$ is the set you want to find the closure of, consider all points $p \notin A$. If it is the case that **any** basic open set containing $p$ must intersect $A$, then $p$ is an adherence point of $A$ and is in the closure (all points of $A$ of course as well, but we don’t have to test them).

As an illustration I''ll do the case $A=(0,\sqrt{2})$.

If $x > \sqrt{2}$ we find some $q \in \Bbb Q$ so that $\sqrt{2} < q < x$ by order denseness of $\Bbb Q$. Also take any rational $q_2 > x$ and note that $x \in [q,q_2)$ and this neighbourhood is disjoint from $A$ so that it is clear that $x \notin \overline{A}$.

For $x=\sqrt{2}$ a basic open neighbout of $x$ is of the form $[q_1, q_2)$ with $q_1 \le \sqrt{2} < q_2$. In fact $q_1 < \sqrt{2}$ and we can find a real $x'>0$ in $(q_1, \sqrt{2})$. This $x$ lies in $A \cap [q_1, q_2)$ so that we have shown that every basic neighbourhood of $\sqrt 2$ intersects $A$, so $\sqrt{2} \in \overline{A}$.

If $x <0$ we find a rational $q \le x$ and then $[q, 0)$ is a basic neighbourhood missing $A$.

If $x=0$ we have that a basic neighbourhood of $0$ can be assumed to be of the form $[0,q)$ with $q >0$ rational. WLOG $q < 2$, say and then $\frac{q}{2} \in [0,q) \cap A$ so also $0 \in \overline{A}$. Hence $\overline{A}=[0,\sqrt 2]$.

Comment: Understood, thanks (+1). Can you maybe please check my proof that I posted...

Comment: @SayanDutta I updated my proof.

Comment: @RIYASUDHEENT.K that’s not a neighbourhood of $\sqrt 2$ at all. It’s left point is irrational.